# python manage.py runserver No module named projectname.settings error message

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a problem that occurred once I moved my Django project to a new Mac.

Once I fired up the virtual environment, I have a problem with running my server. Stacktrace, code, and images attached. Any help is appreciated.

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'fiveminread',
]
```

[settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbqQG.png)

[manage.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t78DL.png)

Comment: What is going wrong? Please explain more in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two virt folder in your directory and make sure that the  virtual enviornment which contains your packages is activated and get rid of the other one